# ASP.NET Core 2 Entity Framework reflection implicitly generates non-existing property for entity class

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am migrating a project from .NET Core 1.1 to .NET Core 2. As part of the migration, for some reason the framework "thinks" that an entity class has a property and the EF includes this property during the query. I tried different experiments to narrow the problem but with no success. I am not sure why this happens and I suspect it might be caused by a bug in the framework either reflection or EF related bug.

Below I will show with an example code what happens.

The class where the problem happens represents an account and is central to the model.

```
public class CompanyAccountProfileEntity
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    //
    // There are many properties here
    //

}
```

Many other enentity classes have foreign key reference to it. The foreign key is typically named `CompanyAccountId`. For example

```
public class PersonEntity
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    //
    // There are many properties here
    //

    public string CompanyAccountId {get; set;}
    [ForeignKey("CompanyAccountId")]
    public virtual CompanyAccountProfileEntity CompanyAccount {get; set;}
}
```

Now, for some reason with .NET Core 2 class CompanyAccountProfileEntity seems to have property `public int? CompanyAccountId` that EF includes in the DB query.

Did anyone else had similar issue or any ideas why this might happen?

Additionally, I tried to explicitly add this property to class `CompanyAccountProfileEntity` with attribute `[NotMapped]`. EF still creates query with this column name.

Comment: Cannot be reproduced with the just two classes provided.

Comment: @IvanStoev I agree with you that cannot be reproduced, also I was aware of that when writing the question but at the moment I don't see any other way except sharing all the code which seems to be impossible to do.

Comment: Ok. One thing you could try is to generate migration (you can remove it after) and see why is that column generated (or where is used).

Comment: @IvanStoev thanks a lot about the tip. I indeed generated the migration and also updated the DB which created a column for that. I couldn't find so far where this property is used. I carefully looked if I wrongly used some attributes like ForeignKey or the fluent API but nothing. The thing is that on .NET Core 1.1 there is no problem. When I have more time I will try to narrow the problem to a smaller subset eliminating files.